# Исключение std::bad_alloc для 2 элементов

Tags: c++, исключения, gcc

Почему следующая программа выбрасывает исключение `std::bad_alloc`?

```
int main() {
    std::vector<char> delimiters = {",", ";"};
    std::cout << delimiters[0];
}
```

Comment: Кстати, в Clang она даже "работает": http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/41c46dc00190683d . Так совпало...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

У Вас очень занятный пример получился. Вот в этой строчке: `std::vector<char> delimiters = {",", ";"};` происходит попытка создать вектор из двух итераторов, т.к. это единственный подходящий конструктор, который компилятору удаётся распознать в этой инициализации: `{",", ";"}`. Т.к. компилятор считает, что ему дают 2 итератора, то он и пытается с ними работать, но на деле это 2 независимых указателя, работа с которыми даёт неопределённое поведение!

Вот поэтому Вы и видите исключение. Компилятор, скорее всего, честно вычел из второго указателя первый, получил какое-то огромное число, попытался выделить и получил `std::bad_alloc`.

Answer (score 3):

Потому что вы говорите о `char`, а передаете строки...

```
std::vector<char> delimiters = {',', ';'};
```

Comment: Так а почему `std::bad_alloc` выбрасывает?

Comment: А это вообще UB получается, по большому счету. И обработка зависит от компилятора. VC++, например, выбрасывает `std::length_error` с сообщением `vector<T> too long`.